# split a path with another path in inkscape

Tags: inkscape, path

Let's say I have a rectangle path and want to split it into two trapezia with another path, let's say with a straight line. 
How can I do this with path operations in Inkscape?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a couple of ways you could do it:

Draw a closed shape such as a rectangle, with a stroke set if you want, and above that draw a path with a stroke - it can be a straight line, or curved.

- Select the top path, then *Object > Stroke to Path*
- Select both shape and the now outlined "stroke"
- *Path > Difference*

[image]

Another simpler method is to draw a closed shape and a single stroke. Again this can be a straight or curved line, open path is also fine. Select both, then *Path > Division*

[image]

Comment: perfect! thank you for solutions to both interpretations of my question.